# signing apk error "other" has different root

Tags: java, android, gradle, code-signing-certificate

recently i make a copy of my android project with other name and then make a ribo on git hub and pushed my project to it but when i want to sign the apk i get this error

```
             FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
        
                      * What went wrong:
                      Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
                      > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
                      > 'other' has different root
        
                      * Try:
                      Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
        
                      * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
        
                      BUILD FAILED in 56s
```

Answer (score 0):

First solution

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```

Second Solution

```
File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...
```

Third Solution
Disable Advanved profiling.Find it here:

```
Run -> Edit Configurations -> Profiling -> Enable advanced profiling
```

Fourth Solution

```
Enable multidex
```